# Pause and Resume Game in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Is there any method to pause a running game and resume back (using a button) in **Phaser-3** framework? The one given for **Phaser-2** is not working.

Comment: check their [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Game.html#event:pauseEvent__anchor)

Comment: @Margon That just gives you the event of when it has been paused, it will not pause the game.

Comment: Pausing the game is done automatically when moved to the background (like visiting another tab). I haven't found a way to pause the main loop, but what I did find is the method to sleep the main loop (the game loop iterates through each scene loop). So if you want to pause all scenes without looping through active scenes, you can do game.loop.sleep(); and game.loop.wake(). This will stop all scenes from updating, but the scenes will stop before their active property changes, so just make sure to check the game loop status along with the scene status if needed.

Comment: @HarryScheuerle thanks, `game.loop.sleep()` and `game.loop.wake()` is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In phaser3 you can have several scenes running in parallel. So you can create a new scene with the resume button and pause the current scene. If you have 2 scenes A e B you can do:

```
# In scene A
this.scene.launch('sceneB')
this.scene.pause();

# Then in sceneB, you can return to sceneA:
button.on('pointerdown', function() {
    this.scene.resume('sceneA');
    this.scene.stop();
})
```

Comment: Looks like is out of date.

Comment: @Totty.js it may not be the ES6 answer but seemed to have worked for him. I would check out all the Scenes examples here: https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=scenes/&q=

Comment: Thanks, looks like there a lot of examples +50 to check. (and they are very slow to load)

Answer (score 3):

Call `game.scene.pause("default")` if you have only the default scene. If you have more call it like this `game.scene.pause(sceneKey)`.

Docs at: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.SceneManager.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to freeze a character, you can use `this.sprite.body.moves = false;`